# WordPress Uploads Directory not using dates in links

Tags: uploads, media-library

I have a WordPress site that was working fine. Suddenly it started looking for media in the wrong folder:

```
www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/path-to-image.jpg
```

This is giving me a 404 because I have always had my content saved as:

```
www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/path-to-image.jpg
```

I've toggled the `Settings > Media > "Organize my files by year and month"` option but this doesn't seem to do anything. What could have changed?

Comment: Check your database and see if `uploads_use_yearmonth_folders` is set to `1`.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee it is.